# Can particles have imaginary momentum / energy less than their rest mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

In the [Feynman lectures on Physics,](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_07.html#Ch7-F5) he talks about quantum tunneling and, basically, there's a non-zero amplitude to be found *in* the barrier, where the particle's energy is below the rest mass, i.e. kinetic energy is negative, and because $E_k = p^2 / (2m)$, that implies $p$ is imaginary.  Can this actually be observed?  Can you collapse the wave function by putting a detector in the barrier and get a count?  What properties does matter have in this state?

Comment: If you have found the particle in the barrier, then you must have just measured its position. This means that the particle is now in a state which is localised in position and consequently it does not have a well defined momentum

Comment: How much does  this differ from the case of bound state? A particle's energy is below it's rest mass and you just need some energy to kick it to another state.

Comment: @Symmetry, but you could have a well-enough defined momentum for the question to still be completely valid. Your detectors' position measurement can have a very large uncertainty for a large-enough barrier.